# Bower and Modernizr

Tags: modernizr, bower

I'm aware that I can create a custom build build of Modernizr to detect the features I care about. But is there a way to use Modernizr installed with Bower to detect a specific feature or set of features (such as SVG support) without including the entire library?

Basically when I do

```
bower install modernizr
```

I will get the entire library which is more than I need.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's not the responsibility of Bower.

You can use [grunt-modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr) to detect which tests you need and build a custom Modernizr version.